# Content script DOM modification doesn't work in a modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension for fun and practice purpose, and I am newbie in Google Chrome-extensions.

I wrote some codes to control the DOM of the pages, and it works fine. Basically, it takes the inputs of type `password` and convert them to `text`.

But when there is a modal in page my DOM manipulation script doesn't work in this case. E.g. the Facebook account deactivation form which is a window popup asking for old password.

I tried to add `"all_frames": true` to `content_scripts` in manifest.json file but it didn't work.

manifest.json file

```
{
  "name":"Password Revealer",
  "version":"0.1",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "description":"It reveals the password type inputs on the web pages",
  "icons":{
    "64":"decrypted.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon":"decrypted.png",
    "default_title":"Password Revealer!",
    "popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
      "run_at":"document_end",
      "all_frames":true
    }
  ]
}
```

myscript.js

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i];
  if (input.type == "password"){
    input.type ="text";
  }
}
```

Comment: _"chrome extension for **fun purpose**"_, _"when deactivating facebook account"_, _"convert input of type password to input of type text"_. Riiiiiiiiight.

Comment: @Xav : what is wrong with fun purpose that to gave -1 to this question by you? while putting this many emphasize on you comment?!

Comment: I don't exactly believe your "fun purpose" claim, but that's irrelevant. 1) You don't know who voted, 2) Votes do not need to be justified, it's an opinion, 3) I did downvote, but because the question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - I believe that your question is not answerable in its current state. I voted to close as well, because there aren't enough details to answer this question. See [How to Ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve it.

Comment: @Xan my codes that I convert input.type=password to input.type=text is already working on the main page, but the popup modal doest work. If you have a solution please kindly answer instead on putting rude answers.

Comment: There can be no solution until you actually show what you're doing. To fix a problem with code, one needs to _see_ the code. Please add *relevant* parts of your code to the question.

Comment: That wasn't hard, was it? I cleaned up your question a bit and retracted my down/close votes. Now it should be possible to answer this - I can't, since I don't have a Facebook account to test your use case and see what the problem is. I suspect it happens because the input field is added after `document_end`, and you'll have to watch for new elements to catch it, e.g. with [mutation-summary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary).

Comment: ^^^ What Xan said. Many sites use AJAX to load dialogs, so they won't exist in the DOM when you call your content script. You would need to attach a function to an AJAX event handler to catch all cases.

Comment: Why don't you create a 'browser action'[button]and on click of that button call that code  like `"browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "normal.png",
        "default_popup": "Toggle/toggle.html"
    }`